# Got 500 error when loading a SSRS report from ASP.NET Core Razor page via iframe to a webform?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, reportingservices-2005

I implemented an ASP.NET Core Razor pages app to display a SSRS report by iframe to a .NET framework webforms on VS 2022.

I deployed the .NET framework webforms and SSRS report to each server and tested I can display the report on the webforms without issues.

Now I run the razor page on VS 2022 to display the SSRS report and got 500 error from Inspect (Developer tools) as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkriN.png).

How to solve this issues? Thanks

Comment: the error message does not indicate the exact issue. enable detailed error logs `if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}`. if SSRS and and razor page is hosted on different domain make sure you have added the CORS to allow requests from the other domain.